# Cell outside virtual DOM cannot be accessed?

Tags: tabulator

I have a quite deep nested `Tabulator` table which has automatic virtual DOM enabled (the default behaviour), which is about 50 rows. The table is inside wrapped inside a `div` with a fixed height of `500px`.
When trying to access an element outside the view with for example this:

```js
row = self.table.getRows(row_index)
cell_element = row.getCell(column_index).getElement()
```

I get the error:

```
row.getCell(...).getElement is not a function
```

To find if I was doing something wrong, I looped over all rows in the table and the above example works for all visible rows plus a few rows above and below, but not for the non-visible ones.
Any ideas what is happening here?

What I'm trying to achieve is to loop through all rows and check if a specific cell index in each row contains a certain string, to set the text weight to `bold` for that cell with:

```js
row = self.table.getRows(row_index)
cell_element = row.getCell(5).getElement()
cell_element.style["fontWeight"] = "bold"
```

Comment: Tabulator uses a virtual DOM to improve render efficiency on large data sets. This means that only the visible rows (and a few above and below) actually exist. As you scroll rows are created and destroyed in realtime as they become visible.

If you describe what you want to do with the element, someone might be able to describe a better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you, added my use example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow for cells to be created and destroyed by the virtual DOM, you need to use a [custom formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom).

```
{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    if (cell.getValue() === 'Look at me') {
        cell.getElement().style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    }
    return cell.getValue();
}
```